# Problems with retargeting apps in weblogic

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c, wlst

I have 2 applications deployed in weblogic:

```
app1: target1, target2
app2: target3
```

And for assigning target2 to app2 I perform next wlst commands:

```
connect('user', 'password', 't3://admin-address:admin-port')
undeploy("app1", targets="target2")
disconnect()
readDomain('domain-dir')
assign("AppDeployment","app2","Target","target2")
updateDomain()
closedomain()
```

There are no errors, but only undeployment of app1 from target2 works. Could someone help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution is:

```
connect('user', 'password', 't3://<admin_server>:<admin_port>')

# remove target from the first application
edit()
startEdit()
cd('/AppDeployments/app1')
set('Targets',jarray.array([ObjectName('com.bea:Name=target1,Type=Server')], ObjectName))
activate()
exit()

# add target to the second application
edit()
startEdit()
cd('/AppDeployments/app2')
set('Targets',jarray.array([ObjectName('com.bea:Name=target2,Type=Server'), ObjectName('com.bea:Name=target3,Type=Server')], ObjectName))
activate()
exit()
```